# Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.modal.open is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I have this component:

```
    export default class ModalDetails extends Vue {
  mounted(): void {
    (this.$refs.modal as any).open();
  }
}
```

which I am trying to test:

```
describe('ModalDetails', () => {
  let wrapper: Wrapper<Vue>;
  let store: Store<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(ModalDetails, {
      localVue,
      store,
    });
}
```

but I am getting this error thrown:
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.modal.open is not a function"

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to mock the function in the test:

```
      const mixinComponent = Vue.extend({
      mixins: [ModalDetails],
      methods: {
        mounted: () => {
          /* empty function */
        },
      },
});
```

then in the component itself:

```
export default class ModalDetails extends Vue {
  mounted(): void {
    this.open();
  }
  open() {
   (this.$refs.modal as any).open();
}
```